# Epoxy flexane mixture for flexible epoxy application

Tags: paint, waterproofing, polyurethane, epoxy

For those who understand plastics and epoxies in particular, curious to know if I can add flexane urethane (or similar elastomer) to epoxy paint without worrying about compatibility issues. IOW will epoxy mix up and be useable in all cases?

For clarity, I am using swimming pool epoxy paint for a waterproof top coating on my rv roof, but would like to ensure it is a bit rubberized and not too brittle. Devcon flexane addition seems to be the answer but I can't find any guidelines for the DIYer.

Thanks for any info. If you have personal experience working with molds, urethanes and epoxy admixtures, you may have valuable knowledge on this.

Product links:

[https://www.amazon.com/Olympic-Poxolon-Two-Coat-Epoxy-Swimming/dp/B07BLMHKBK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BLMHKBK)
https://www.reynoldsam.com/product/flexer-epoxy-flexibilizer/